# Why do negative numpy.float64 yield nan when expontiated with a fractional number?

Tags: python, numpy, complex-numbers

A negative `numpy.float64` exponentiated with a fractional (i.e., decimal, i.e., rational) number will yield a `nan` result and a warning.

The same number using Python's `float` type returns a `complex` result.

Here is a minimal example using Python 3.6.6 (for a comment on Python 2.7.15, see below):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> f = -2.0
>>> npf = np.float64(-2.0)
>>> f**1.1
(-2.0386342710747223-0.6623924280875919j)
>>> npf ** 1.1
__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
nan
```

I tried the `numpy.power` function getting a different warning and the same result.

```
>>> np.power(f, 1.1)
__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power
nan
>>> np.power(npf, 1.1)
nan
```

The warning in the latter appears only after whatever is executed first.

I ran into this using `numpy.array`s of floats, which in all other cases(?) just behave the same as Python floats. The conversion from `float` to `numpy.float64` happens implicitly so it took me a while to find the source of the problem.

Now, I can get around this by explicitly converting to or specifying the `dtype` when creating the array as `numpy.complex`:

```
>>> npc = np.complex(-2.0)
>>> npc ** 1.1
(-2.0386342710747223-0.6623924280875919j)
>>> np.power(npc, 1.1)
(-2.0386342710747223-0.66239242808759191j)
```

(note the different precision of the output O_o, I can live with that, though)

**My question is:** Why?? Why doesn't numpy return a `numpy.complex` when necessary. It *does* convert to `numpy.float64` when, e.g., dividing a `numpy.int64`:

```
>>> ai = np.array([1])
>>> ai.dtype
dtype('int64')
>>> ai/2
array([ 0.5])
>>> (ai/2).dtype
dtype('float64')
```

Why not apply the same philosophy when `numpy.float64` is not capable of expressing the result of a calculation and use `numpy.complex64` instead?

**comment on Python 2.7.15:** with this version, exponentiating a `float` with a fractional number throws an exception, explicitly using `complex` solves the problem:

```
>>> f ** 1.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: negative number cannot be raised to a fractional power
>>> complex(-2.0) ** 1.1
(-2.0386342710747223-0.6623924280875919j)
```

This is equivalent to the behaviour of numpy.

Comment: Same reason [you can't raise a numpy integer to a negative power](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43287311/why-cant-i-raise-to-a-negative-power-in-numpy); the output dtype is based on the input dtypes, not the input values.

Comment: @user2357112: the output dtype is *not* based on the input dtypes, at least not consistently, as shown in the example where a `numpy.int64` is divided and yields a `numpy.float64` result.

Comment: And if you tried that with any other `numpy.int64`, you would also get a `numpy.float64`. It doesn't matter what the value of the int64 is; knowing the dtypes of the inputs is enough to know that the result will be a float64.

Comment: You may have misinterpreted my first comment as saying that the operation doesn't matter for determining the dtype. The operation matters; different operations on two int64 values can give different dtypes, but the same operation on different int64 values will have a consistent output dtype, barring type "demotion" on mixed scalar/array operations.

Comment: @user2357112 : yes, now I see... you are right. And while in the case of the division it is not a big deal going from int64 to float64, it *is* (e.g. memory-wise) going from float64 to complex. mmhh.. makes sense and I don't like it O_o

Answer (score 0):

Probably the numpy developers just did not think to cover this case. You could put up an issue on [Github](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues). Otherwise, you will just have to do the `complex` conversion explicitly. It would be good to put in the issue so that the numpy developers can work on it.