# How to mutliply a number with negative power in python

Tags: python, math

When I try to multiply this by a negative integer it just returns an error

[image: power]

I use:

`A = np.array([[1,2,0], [2,4,-2], [0,-2,3]])`

Comment: Are you sure A is a number?

Comment: It references a matrix

Comment: And are you sure that's not a matrix inverse?

Comment: So are you actually asking how to invert a matrix?

Comment: From the photo we can see that this is homework and that you need the inverse of the matrix A -- see my answer

Comment: This is the matrix: A = np.array([[1,2,0], [2,4,-2], [0,-2,3]])

Comment: see my answer and let me know then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the screenshot, I can see this is homework.

### So it asks for the **matrix inverse.** In maths this is written as `A^(-1)`

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1,2,0], [2,4,-2], [0,-2,3]])
np.linalg.inv(A)
```

```
array([[-2.  ,  1.5 ,  1.  ],
       [ 1.5 , -0.75, -0.5 ],
       [ 1.  , -0.5 ,  0.  ]])
```

Answer (score 0):

In numpy, you can not raise integers by negative integer powers (Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43287311/why-cant-i-raise-to-a-negative-power-in-numpy)).

In python, the `**` operator returns the value without any error.

```
In [6]: A = 20                                                                                                                                                                          

In [7]: print(A ** -1)                                                                                                                                                                  
0.05
```

You can also use `pow()`,

```
In [1]: A = 20

In [2]: pow(20, -1)
Out[2]: 0.05
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're working with matrices, it's a good idea to ensure that they are instances of the `numpy.matrix` type rather than the more-generic `numpy.ndarray`.

```
import numpy as np
M = np.matrix([[ ... ]])
```

To convert an existing generic array to a matrix you can also pass it into `np.asmatrix()`.

Once you have a `matrix` instance `M`, one way to get the inverse is `M.I`

To avoid the "integers not allowed" problem, ensure that the `dtype` of your matrix is floating-point, not integer (specify `dtype=float` in the call to `matrix()` or `asmatrix()`)

Comment: On the contrary, if you're working with matrices, you should use `numpy.ndarray` and *not* the `numpy.matrix` type. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/53254738/270986.

Answer (score -1):

To Insert power as negative value assume an another variable and name it "pow" and assign that negative value. 
Now put below in your code.

```
pow = -3
value = 5**pow
print(value)
```

Execute the code and you will see result.
Hope it helps...