# How do you iterate through multiple arrays and substitute values into an equation?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, loops

Don't know if I phrased the question correctly because it's sort of hard to explain. But I have three arrays which represent temperature, salinity, and depth. They're massive so I've put the simplified versions of them below just to get the gist:

```
t = (np.arange(26)[25:21:-1]).reshape(2,2)
s = (np.arange(34,35,0.25).reshape(2,2))
z = (np.arange(0,100,25).reshape(2,2))
```

I have this equation here (also stripped down for simplicity):

```
velocity = 1402.5 + 5*(t) - (5.44 * 10**(-2) * t**(-2))  + (2.1 * 10**(-4) * t**(3)) + 1.33*(s) - (1.56*10**(-2)*z)
```

What I want to do is to iterate through the values from the t,s,z arrays and have them substituted into the equation to calculate velocity for each case. I want the resultant value to then append into a new array with the same configuration - (2,2) in this case. I can't seem to figure out the best way to approach this, so any sort of feedback would be appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the same equation as-is with one change:

velocity = 1402.5 + 5*(t) - (5.44 * 10**(-2.0) * t**(-2.0))  + (2.1 * 10**(-4) * t**(3)) + 1.33*(s) - (1.56*10**(-2)*z)

Change: `t**(-2)` has been changed to `t**(-2.0)`. To better understand why we need to change the type of the exponent see the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43287598/13389591.

The above gives the output:

```
[[1576.00116296 1570.56544556]
 [1565.15996716 1559.7834676 ]]
```