# Why is the dictionary lookup not faster in this case?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, lookup

I recently asked about [the fastest way to create powers of ten](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69788338/5472354), and it turned out that the fastest way is actually a bit of a [sneaky workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69790043/5472354), where you create all the possible values first, and then simply look them up whenever you need them.

In the solution, a `list` was used as the lookup-table, however, I've just learned that `dicts` **[should be much faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/513906/5472354)** when it comes to lookup operations (see e.g. also [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/faster-lookups-in-python-1d7503e9cd38)). But when I tried out a `dict` as the lookup table, the **process was actually slower**:

```py
n = 200
 18 ns   18 ns   18 ns  f[n]  # list
 22 ns   22 ns   22 ns  g[n]  # dict

n = -200
 18 ns   18 ns   18 ns  f[n]  # list
 29 ns   29 ns   29 ns  g[n]  # dict
```

Why is that? Does it have to do with the fact that the `keys` are integers and not strings? (Also I guess `sets` cannot be used in this case?)

Here is the code I ran:

```py
from timeit import repeat


solutions = [
    'f[n]  # list',
    'g[n]  # dict',
]

for n in 200, -200:
    print(f'n = {n}')
    setup = f'''
n = {n}
f = [10.0 ** i for i in [*range(309), *range(-323, 0)]]
g = {{i: 10.0 ** i for i in range(-323, 309)}}
'''
    for solution in solutions:
        try:
            ts = sorted(repeat(solution, setup, repeat=50))[:3]
        except OverflowError:
            ts = [None] * 3
        print(
            *('%3d ns ' % (t * 1e3) if t else ' error ' for t in ts), solution
        )
    print()
```

Comment: For me, the interesting thing here is that dict becomes significantly slower for the negative value, while the list is unaffected by that. If you add `hash(n)` to the tested expressions, you'll likely see that that gets much slower for the negative value as well. Don't yet know why.

Comment: @KellyBundy I think that is likely due to Python's caching of small integers (in the range of something like -1 to 256, IIRC). Integers outside of this range have to be created as new GC'd objects. It's slightly faster to index keys that are identical rather than merely equal, and I imagine if the indexing is the only operation performed, that difference might actually be fairly significant.

Comment: @KellyBundy In CPython 3.10, the cached integers are `-5 <= n <= 256` . You can check it by running e.g. `[a for a, b in zip(range(-300, 300), range(-300, 300)) if a is not b]`

Comment: Yes, that seems to be it. That was my first suspicion, but then a test showed no slowing down for numbers larger than 256, but seems that was because I had only used the default `repeat` value as well or had low CPU share. Closer longer inspection at the borders ...

Comment: ... [shows the effect](https://tio.run/##hVLLasMwELz7K@YSJAW7NHbsPCCnQs89pKeQg9soscCRjaRQQum3uyvZuKQPanaZ1c5otSu5vbqq0dmyNV3HGMP22qrXsoaR9lI7i7dKajw8PcNWpZFQFpU6VeCUp6VTZ2nhCevKl1qKKEIxg7YAivQGk4W3x7K28m9N4W3QzOc9N2Lea3JvW3P5TdJjMvc2SLKBusU0z4P/IyqC96Kx1@wG03wR/Ptkt5jmy@C9arzPNVarO9o8iejuo@homnO4U@Wgzm1jHL1DK0tHVGOgoTR2U1Pqk@TJIkaSiRjDmqaJ6YiV2K8jOhf0dhtYKiEPvC/CWVXaimvBYhyZJvpdf1Dcs5v8XojdOtuH3a1R2vEQ@m/K2SQ7@EkYJuAOU8xkJqCOcJA0EuWlMdQjg@/U@U6dFfFYQX@FQxc/Ev7n0iEpuu4T) there.

Comment: Hmm, actually only the `hash` function seems affected, [not dict access](https://tio.run/##hVJNb8IwDL33V7wLSoLKBO3KRydOk3begZ0Qh24NNFJJqyRoQojf3jmBMY0JVtmK4/fkZztt965qdDptTdcxxrDYt@qjqGGk3dXO4rOSGs@vb7BVYSSURaU2FTjl6erUVlp4wLrivZYijyKkCbQFrs/BxNtLUVt5mzP29g8n87YwuzuUR29nyugM/T6TLAt@RfpdJ8nGwe@KJdkk@HfXt/SmwU@s6LLRHLPZA0n0Itp@FK1Nsw1bVQ5q2zbG0Uu0snAENQYaSmPZN4XeSD6YxBikIsb5TuPEpDETqzwiYdDrzWGphCz5qQhn5VKvWIw104Qd9PEJpQ8OFOYYHo@Enajz0VCIZZ6uQqnWKO14CP3X56yXln4uhh64Qx8jmQqoNRwkDUh5aQw1zODbdr5tZ0V8qaB/wqqwFdfiT8L/azokRdd9AQ).

Comment: For dict access it [seems to be due to collisions](https://tio.run/##fVFBbtswELzzFQMUBkVDDmQzAWIBPgW9tj2kJ0EH1aYsAjIpkHRTI/DbHa7kqFYaVAcNuDs7yxl2p9BYIx87d7lwzvF86vS2auGUP7bB46VRBk8/fsI3lVPQHo3eN0hiPR6DPigPavhQ/WqVyBkz2GCVZQxyBeMBSDnBujAl8AUHbTR2ehtumFPcX5k9qdddTIWn@Inw/ePA@IBT4dFdjvX67mGJGYtJMFY7e@gd6gB96KwLMZVOVXGEedseg7ZRbIOCRWXwf9bzdGjcbou1MipbBwNtKKe0N5X31M5pE5Kak9VXc@air3oVjl2s1HSra4vVhK86xzK7yzCfQ4NUNakWi143/srzme3/w3SV2atkIVcyhczWItJpCW0lzrtLoo6Oh6vSF9zp76EvUBw@BqV2yRBV8j6WDjbSa4SbVSZEkctynFd/tqoL@P5bubq1L1@ds@4T9eKbNarEHHLsDalNqPOEz@SO3ppjhiRE/lJJAV0jQLVexbqiDRHJaCCHwYt0tDnKiZuXEZfLGw)

Comment: @Jasmijn Argh, testing the whole range `for n in range(-323, 309):` with the full dict on my PC (so I can run it longer) does seem affected by that [-5, 256] range again. I get pretty consistent 137 ns for range [-323,-6], then 109 ns for [-5,0] except 183 ns for -1, then 108 ns for [1,256], then 136 ns for [257,308].

Comment: @KellyBundy Yeah, I think small dictionaries might also have some optimizations that interfere with your earlier results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`collection[key_or_index]` is O(1) for both `list` and `dict`. What is different is the performance of `key_or_value in collection`.

It's the difference between "What is the `i`th power of ten in my list?" versus "Is `x` a power of ten that is in my list?"

Indexing is slightly faster for list because dictionaries need to calculate the hash of their key, as well as check for collisions.

---

The confusion is because "lookup" can refer both to the indexing operation as well as checking for presence, depending on the context.

---

Here is an overview of how to do the equivalent operation in both lists and dictionaries:

|  | List | Dictionary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Indexing | `lst[i]` | `dct[key]` |
| Checking for presence of key/index | `-len(lst) <= i < len(lst)` | `key in dct` |
| Checking for presence of value | `value in lst` | `value in dct.values()` |
| Looping over values | `for value in lst` | `for value in dct.values()` |
| Looping over keys/indexes | `for i in range(len(lst))` | `for key in dct` |
| Looping over both | `for i, value in enumerate(lst)` | `for key, value in dct.items()` |

Comment: Thanks! That makes a lot of sense. I wasn't aware that the term "lookup" is ambiguous. Unfortunately, I'm getting downvoted for some reason, so I might delete the post...

Comment: I hope you don't delete the post, it's a good question, and I don't think you'll be the last person who had this misunderstanding. I hope you also check out the table I've just added, listing how the ways to use lists and dictionaries differ!

Comment: @mapf don't delete this question, because it would also delete this answer. The table is really useful for beginners too.