# Vectorized function fails to evaluate

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I'm having troubles with a vectorized function:

```py
def func(y):
    return sum(x**(-y) for x in range(1, 10))
vect_func = np.vectorize(func)
vect_func([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

# Output:
# ValueError: Integers to negative integer powers are not allowed.
```

Whereas the following works just fine:

```py
[func(t) for t in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]

# Output:
# [2.8289682539682537, 1.5397677311665408, 1.1965319856741932, 1.0819365834937567, 1.0368973413446938]
```

Is it possible to get `np.vectorize` to work on this example?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I raise to a negative power in numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43287311/why-cant-i-raise-to-a-negative-power-in-numpy)

Comment: Why are you trying to use `vectorize` if the list comprehension works just fine?

Comment: @hpaulj because in my application `func` is an arbitrary function with an arbitrary number of arguments. It just so happens that that particular function is creating problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a function doesn't work in `np.vectorize`, it's a good idea to verify what the argument is.

Let's add a `type` print to the function:

```
In [36]: def func(y):
    ...:     print(type(y))
    ...:     return sum(x**(-y) for x in range(1, 10))
    ...:
```

In the list comprehension, Python `int` are passed:

```
In [37]: func(3)
<class 'int'>
Out[37]: 1.1965319856741932
```

with the `vectorized` version:

```
In [40]: vect_func(3)
<class 'numpy.int64'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-40-65e2816d8003>", line 1, in <module>
    vect_func(3)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 2163, in __call__
    return self._vectorize_call(func=func, args=vargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 2241, in _vectorize_call
    ufunc, otypes = self._get_ufunc_and_otypes(func=func, args=args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 2201, in _get_ufunc_and_otypes
    outputs = func(*inputs)
  File "<ipython-input-36-311d525a60ba>", line 3, in func
    return sum(x**(-y) for x in range(1, 10))
  File "<ipython-input-36-311d525a60ba>", line 3, in <genexpr>
    return sum(x**(-y) for x in range(1, 10))
ValueError: Integers to negative integer powers are not allowed.
```

`y` is not a python `int`,  it is a `numpy` int.

```
In [41]: func(np.int64(3))
<class 'numpy.int64'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-41-c34830937ffd>", line 1, in <module>
    func(np.int64(3))
  File "<ipython-input-36-311d525a60ba>", line 3, in func
    return sum(x**(-y) for x in range(1, 10))
  File "<ipython-input-36-311d525a60ba>", line 3, in <genexpr>
    return sum(x**(-y) for x in range(1, 10))
ValueError: Integers to negative integer powers are not allowed.
```

If we deliberately pass Python `int` it works:

```
In [42]: vect_func(np.array([1,2,3], object))
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
Out[42]: array([2.82896825, 1.53976773, 1.19653199])
```

`np.vectorize` can be handy when passing several arrays to a scalar function, and you want to take advantage of `broadcasting`.  But for a list, or lists that can be zipped, it doesn't add anything to a list comprehension - not even speed.

And as this case illustrates, it has some gotchas than can catch the novice (and even more experienced users).  Here it's the nature of the input.  For many other SO questions, it's nature of the return value (the automatic `otypes`).