# Wierd behavior with raising intgers to the negative powers in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am observing this weird behavior when I am raising an integer to the negative power using an `np.array`. Specifically, I am doing

```
import numpy as np

a = 10**(np.arange(-1, -8, -1))
```

and it results in the following error.

> ValueError: Integers to negative integer powers are not allowed.

This is strange as the code `10**(-1)` works fine. However the following workaround (where `10` is a float instead of integer) works fine.

```
import numpy as np

a = 10.**(np.arange(-1, -8, -1)
print(a)  # Prints array([1.e-01, 1.e-02, 1.e-03, 1.e-04, 1.e-05, 1.e-06, 1.e-07])
```

Why is it not valid for integers? Any explanation is appreciated.

Comment: Interesting that `10**-8` works and yields `1e-08`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because the input 10 is an integer.

```
10**(np.arange(-1, -8, -1))
```

`numpy.arange()` is designed such a way that that has to give `10**(np.arange(-1, -8, -1))` integers or nothing since input is an integer.

On the contrary;

```
a = 10.**(np.arange(-1, -8, -1)
```

gives results happily as `10.0` is a `float`

---

**Edit:** found an answer to back my point; voted for a duplicate:

[Why can't I raise to a negative power in numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43287311/why-cant-i-raise-to-a-negative-power-in-numpy)

Comment: Is the problem with `numpy.arange` or with the power operator in numpy array?